# kinetic js, how can I improve resolution of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, kineticjs

I am new to use kinetic js, and I think that it is so good library, the problem is the resolution of the elements, I know that kinetic js doesn't use svg, but the resolution is horrible, I am creating circles and sample shape with animations, but these look like poor images and I don't want that. 
Somebody know a solution or definitely it is impossible to change the resolution ?

For example I create the elements like this:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
  x: this.stage.getWidth() / 2,
  y: this.stage.getHeight() / 2 + 10,
  radius: radius,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  draggable: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post an example?

It's possible that your animation is trying to draw frames faster than they can be properly rendered--causing ghosts/blurs.  If you throttle down your framerate, is the "horribleness" reduced?

These static shape results between KineticJS, native-Canvas and SVG look the same to me.

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pgBv4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
#canvas{ border:1px solid red; }
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,100,75,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 10,
      radius: 75,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(circle);
    layer.draw();



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
    <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle x="100" y="100" r="75" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```